# The photos do not appear after upgrade

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart2.3

I have successfully Upgrade 2.0.x to 2.3.x
But I do not see the pictures on the site,
With it's found in the admin panel

this is my website aleamarwadicor.com

my image directory image/catalog

Comment: Have you checked the permalinks? The other idea is that the update changed the permalink structure and you need to update these links.

Comment: how can id do that

Comment: Go to settings -> Uploads and check if you can see any pictures

Comment: yes in admin panel it's appear, but on the website it's do not appear

Comment: If you can see pictures, go to Products -> Image and check if the images are set to the product. If they are not set you have to do this manual. Tell m e if its working

Comment: i don't see this option on opencart 2.3.x

Comment: I'm at a system right now. Go to your products okay? After this edit a product. When the editor for the product is open you should see an image option

Comment: yes the image appears there

Comment: Okay thats crazy. I don't know other options without see whats going on. Sorry mate :/

Comment: If you trust me you can make a login for me and I'll take a look on it.

Comment: Sorry I really don't know whats going on without take a look on it

Comment: Don't post your login data here!!!!!!!!

Comment: If its critical

Comment: I can't speak arabic. Is it okay for you when I change it for this moment to englisch?

Comment: ok No Problem change to english, or use google translation

Comment: It looks like that the images are destroyed after the update. You have to reset the images to your products :) Hope I helped you! I'm logged out. You just need to change the language back

Comment: thanks but how can i reset the images , did you mean should i reupload it

Comment: Yes, reupload and make a good structure. After this you have to go to your products and select the new images.

Answer (score 0):

There's no source in your images tag. See below:

[image]

Comment: Yes, but it's found in the Control Panel, and were working in the previous version

Comment: Check the error log. Normally found under `system >log` when you go to the public_html folder

Comment: check that error logging is enabled on your database in the `settings` table or in the backend under the store settings

Comment: it's enabled there